# Android Compose IncompatibleComposeRuntimeVersionException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Compose Compiler requires the Compose Runtime to be on the class path, but none could be found. The compose compiler plugin you are using (version 1.5.1) expects a minimum runtime version of 1.0.0.

An error occurred: implementation(libs.androidx.runtime)
was added, but the error still appears.

Comment: You will need to share what compose artifacts you depend on in which version and which kotlin version you are using.